# How can handle exception in Spring security 3

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security

now I am confused about the Spring Security 3.07+STRUTS 2+Exception problem,I used   Spring Security 3.07+STRUTS 2+ibatis2 ,
in order to handle Exception,I used Struts 2 Global Exceptipo and custom an interceptor,
if i don't use spring security 3,it works fine,it can handle any kind of exceptions or error and give the message:
here is the struts.xml:

```
       <interceptors>
                    <interceptor name="myexception"
                            class="com.itownet.isms.core.exception.ExceptionInteceptor"></interceptor>
                    <interceptor-stack name="paramsStack">
                            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                                    <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
                            </interceptor-ref>
                            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                                    <param name="excludeParams">.*\\u0023.*</param>
                            </interceptor-ref>

                            <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
                            <interceptor-ref name="myexception"></interceptor-ref>

                    </interceptor-stack>
            </interceptors>

            <default-interceptor-ref name="paramsStack" />
            <global-results>
                    <result name="error">/jsp/error/error.jsp</result>
                    <result name="globalError" type="redirect">
                            <param name="location">/home/home!error.action</param>
                            <param name="errorMsg">${errorMsg}</param>
                    </result>
            </global-results>
            <global-exception-mappings>
                    <exception-mapping result="globalError"     exception="java.lang.Exception"></exception-mapping>
    <exception-mapping result="globalError" exception="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException"></exception-mapping>
    <exception-mapping result="globalError" exception="java.lang.RuntimeException"></exception-mapping>
    <exception-mapping result="globalError" exception="com.itownet.isms.core.exception.ServiceException"></exception-mapping>
            </global-exception-mappings>
```

but when i use spring security,for example,here:

public class MyAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager
{

```
public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object,
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) throws AccessDeniedException,
        InsufficientAuthenticationException, RuntimeException,ServiceException {

        user = this.userService.get(userId);
```

}

as you know ,it may be thrown some exception if the db is not ready,and will throw RuntimeException.But i want to know how Spring security can handle DataAccess Exception and  RuntimeException?
    first i want to custome ExceptionTranslationFilter:
public class MyExceptionTranslationFilter extends ExceptionTranslationFilter {
    protected void sendStartAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain,
            AuthenticationException reason) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        boolean isAjax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(req
                .getHeader("X-Requested-With"));

```
    if (isAjax) {
        String jsonObject = "{\"message\":\"Please login first.\","
                + "\"access-denied\":true,\"cause\":\"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE\"}";
        String contentType = "application/json";
        resp.setContentType(contentType);
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print(jsonObject);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        return;
    }

    super.sendStartAuthentication(req, resp, chain, reason);
}
    <beans:bean id="exceptionTranslator"
            class="com.itownet.isms.security.MyExceptionTranslationFilter">
            <beans:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />

            <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint"
                    ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />
    </beans:bean>
```

but when i debug,i find   ExceptionTranslationFilter  will not handle dataacess exception and runtimeexception!
ExceptionTranslationFilter only handles two exceptions AuthenticationException and AccessDeniedException with custom handlers for these two exceptions, what about any other type of exception or even run time exceptions?
   so i can not find any idea,and my own struts2 custom interceptors will not be invoked!and of course
it can not handle the spring security's exception!Any Good Idea?